# Change view background gradient color with smooth animation while scrolling in tableView with multiple section

Tags: ios, swift, animation, tableview, gradient

> I have multiple section in my UITableView, i want to change my View
>   back ground color as gradient color with smooth transition while
>   scrolling tableView.
>
> when new section comes in tableView change view background color
>   smoothly.

**How can i achieve this kind of Animation.?**

> My Code is below for change the background color but not smoothly

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        switch section {
        case 0:
                self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
            break
        case 1:
               self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            break
        case 2:
               self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            break
        case 3:
               self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            break
        case 4:
               self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
            break
        default:
              self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
            break
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please include your current codes, screenshots. This question seems to be unclear

Comment: I'm not sure. Try adding this chnage of color in animation blocka and change the alpha in the animation block 0.5 to 1. That should give you that effect. If not you have work with layers here.

Comment: Yes but when i adding in Animation block its not working smoothly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: 
UIView, forSection section: Int) {

    switch section {
    case 0:
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseIn, .curveEaseOut, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {() -> Void in
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan.withAlphaComponent(0.4)

        })

    case 1:
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseIn, .curveEaseOut, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {() -> Void in
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.4)

        })

    case 2:
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseIn, .curveEaseOut, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {() -> Void in
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow.withAlphaComponent(0.4)

        })

    case 3:
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseIn, .curveEaseOut, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {() -> Void in
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange.withAlphaComponent(0.4)

        })

    case 4:
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseIn, .curveEaseOut, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {() -> Void in
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.magenta.withAlphaComponent(0.4)

        })

    default:
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown

    }
}
```

Comment: how to set gradient color instead of simple UIColor with all section ?

Comment: Code can be written in a more optimized way using a single function instead of repeating animation code, code refactoring can be applied here.

Comment: @vaibhav Yes, it can be written more optimized way. but I am not here to optimized the code.

Comment: Okay, the purpose why we here is to provide the better ans to op.

Comment: the solution you are saying it will only remove the duplicate code. it will not change the complexity of the code. so if you will not remove that then also it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

> You can change view gradient color smoothly with this code -

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    for layer in self.view.layer.sublayers! {
        if layer .isKind(of: CAGradientLayer.self) {
            layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
    }
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = self.view.bounds
    gradient.colors = [self.generateRandomColor().cgColor, self.generateRandomColor().cgColor]
    let anim:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: "opacity")
    anim.fromValue = 0.5
    anim.toValue = 1
    anim.duration = 1.0
    gradient.add(anim, forKey: "opacity")
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

func generateRandomColor() -> UIColor {
    let hue : CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random() % 256) / 256 + 0.5
    let saturation : CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random() % 128) / 256 + 0.5
    let brightness : CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random() % 128) / 256 + 0.5
    return UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: saturation, brightness: brightness, alpha: 0.5)
}
```

Comment: yes working fine this but how to set gradient color instead of UICoor

Comment: you need to add gradient layer. for that